# Cannot find module 'nodemailer' in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a simple nodejs code to send a test email using AWS Lambda function and SES services.

I was able to deploy my function to AWS with all proper access rights and requirements, etc...

Unfortunately, whenever I test my function in AWS Lambda console, I get the error "Cannot find module 'nodemailer'" which I required in my code below.

From my project structure I seem to have it installed properly, or maybe not.

I've been stuck in this issue for days now, what am I doing wrong here? Btw, I am new to nodejs and aws.

Thank you in advance.

**NOTE:** I tried running this in the command and it is working fine, I was able to receive the email.
command: node handler.js

**Project Screenshot:**

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3LS0.png)

**Nodejs Code:**

```
'use strict';

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: 'USER_XXX',
    pass: 'PASSWORD_XXX'
  }
});

var text = 'Hi,\r\n\r\n'
     + 'This email is a test email!\r\n\r\n'
     + 'This is sent using NodeMailer module in Nodejs thru AWS SES SMTP Host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.\r\n\r\n'
     + 'Thanks!';

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'ses@aws.net',
  to: 'me@aws.net',
  subject: 'Test Email (NodeMailer & AWS SES)',
  text: text
};

module.exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  console.log('Email Sending...');
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
          if(error){
            console.log(error);
          }else{
            console.log('Message sent');
          }
      });
};
```

**Lambda Test Error Message:**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'nodemailer'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/handler.js:2:18)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where's your packages file?

Comment: You should install module `nodemailer` in your PC first, then copy all file (all files and folders(test project as I saw)) and input to lambda

Comment: Hi Adrian, do you mean the package.json file? Sorry I'm really new in here...

Comment: Hi Thanh, I already did, in fact I documented the steps on how I did it.

Comment: Step #1 - Create User
 - Go To AWS Dashboard
 - Select IAM 
 - Create User
 - Give administrator access

Step #2 - Install serverless framework
 command: npm i serverless -g
 command: serverless help or sls help to display list of commands
  
Step #3 - Create Project
 command: sls project create
 --> provide necessary info for questions
 --> sls will create the project structure (Open with Atom)

Comment: Step #4 - Create Function
 command: sls function create
 --> provide necessary info for questions
 --> for sendemail, install nodemailer
  command: npm install nodemailer
  command: npm install nodemailer-smtp-transport

Step #5 - Deploy Project
 command: sls dash deploy

Comment: @LordCruise did you solve the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have `nodemailer` as one of the dependencies in your package.json.